# Bash/unix sort "YYYY-[N]NN"

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a list like this -

`2009-96 2010-100 2010-101 2010-97 2010-98 2010-99 2009-99a 2011-102`

How do I sort the numbers in the right order, so that it's sorted by first 4 digits (year) if the year is different, otherwise it is sorted by the digit after `-`?

The right output which I want is -

`2009-96 2009-99a 2010-97 2010-98 2010-99 2010-100 2010-101 2011-102`

Comment: What to do about "2009-99a"? Ignore the "a"?

Comment: Also, your output is not sorted numerically by year - you have 2099-99a after 2010-99

Comment: @theglauber Thanks, I corrected the order.

Comment: Please ignore the "a" if that makes it simpler. However it does exist in the problem I'm struggling with, as these are names of some production files that have been created over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your version of `sort`, because the command line options may be different, but on my system, `sort -t - -k 1,1n -k 2,2n <filename>` works.

Comment: This does not work because 2010-100 and 2010-101 comes before 2010-97.

Comment: Sorry - this one does work - the comment I wrote above was for a different answer (or so I thought)! Either there's something wrong with the Stackoverflow system or I'm going crazy.

Comment: Wait why does my comment above come from dj_segfault? ... I think I wrote a similar comment to some other response, and this answer doesn't work on dj_segfault's machine so he wrote this comment here. And I had a deja vu because it is similar to my comment to a response - which doesn't seem to exist any more (was deleted?).

Comment: Yes, I did try it, but in Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sort (std on Linux):

```
sort -t'-' -n
```

`sort` sorts lines, so convert your space delimiters to `\n` and back using `tr` as shown in @dimba's answer.

Comment: Although exactly that doesn't work in my case, `sort -t'-' -k2n` works

Comment: Ahh... I guess that's probably because in my code it is only sorting by second field, and the first field happened to be sorted in the input I was using.

Comment: I see you're right. I tested it but apparently I missed that the ordering wasn't right on the second field. Anyway I agree @twalberg has the correct solution.